# How to add space from the bottom under the custom tabbar?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uitabbar, tabbar

I'm trying to find an option to add a distance the size of a `bottomBar` to each `View`, as the native `TabView` does (so that the content does not leave under it. With the ability to change this distance depending on whether the bottom bar is shown).
I hide the native `TabView` at the application level and use it only as a container for screens.

```
UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
```

I tried to add `.padding`, but then `TabView` doesn't save `background` from `content`.

```
import SwiftUI

public struct ShapedTabView<Content: View>: View {
  // MARK: Lifecycle
  
  public init(
    tabs: [TabType],
    selection: Binding<TabType>,
    @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (TabType) -> Content
  ) {
    self.tabs = tabs
    self._selection = selection
    self.content = content
  }
  
  // MARK: Public
  
  public var body: some View {
      TabView(selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(tabs, id: \.rawValue) { tab in
            content(tab) // .padding(.bottom, isHide ? 0 : 90)
              .tag(tab)
          }
      }
      .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
        BottomBar(
          selection: $selection,
          localSelection: selection,
          tabs: tabs
        )
        .offset(x: 0.0, y: isHide ? 170 : 0)
        .opacity(isHide ? 0 : 1)
        .disabled(isHide)
      }
    .environment(\.isTabBarHide, $isHide)
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
  }
  
  // MARK: Private

  private var tabs: [TabType]
  @Binding
  private var selection: TabType
  @ViewBuilder
  private let content: (TabType) -> Content
  
  @State
  private var isHide = false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move `safeAreaInsets` to the `View` level, which are passed to `Content`. Works great